# How to apply re-score plugin to elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

There is rescore plugin implementation example
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/examples/rescore
provided by ES community

The question is how to apply it to the query?

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/examples/rescore/src/test/resources/rest-api-spec/test/example-rescore/20_score.yml

Answer (score 2):

```
GET test-idx/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "fullName" : "some-name"
        }
    },
    "rescore" : {
        "window_size" : 2,
        "example" : {        //check this line
             "factor":2.0
         }
    }
}
```